# GetFileAttributesW causes Access violation reading location x (GetLastError returns 8)

Tags: c, winapi

I am currently trying to implement a program that loads multiple files into memory, for further processing. To see if the file exists I made a function that uses GetFileAttributesW to check if the file indeed exists.

The first file gets loaded correctly, but once I try to load the second file, I get the access violation (GetLastError returns 8; ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY). I can safely rule out that I don't have enough RAM, as the files are max. 500kb in size and I am never loading more than 20 (I have 16GB of RAM).
I also have rights to access he file, etc.

```
inline BOOL FileExists(const TCHAR* szPath)
{
    DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributesW(szPath); // ERROR here (1st iteration everything is fine) 

    return (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && !(dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
}

.
.
.

FILE_DATA LoadFileIntoMemory(const TCHAR* FileName)
{
    PTCHAR FinalPath = VirtualAlloc(NULL, MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    PTCHAR FilePath = L"C:\\Users\\invasi0nZ\\"; // 

    concat(FinalPath, FilePath, MAX_PATH);
    concat(FinalPath, FileName, MAX_PATH);

    if (!FileExists(FinalPath))
    {
        memset(FinalPath, 0, MAX_PATH);

        FilePath = L"C:\\Users\\invasi0nZ\\Documents\\";

        concat(FinalPath, FilePath, MAX_PATH);
        concat(FinalPath, FileName, MAX_PATH);
    }

    HANDLE File = CreateFileW(FinalPath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (File == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return (FILE_DATA){ NULL, NULL };
    }

    int FileSize = GetFileSize(File, NULL);

    PBYTE RawFile = VirtualAlloc(NULL, FileSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    DWORD dwRead;
    size_t FileSize = GetFileSize(File, NULL);

    ReadFile(File, RawFile, FileSize, &dwRead, NULL);

    CloseHandle(File);
    VirtualFree(FinalPath, sizeof(FinalPath), MEM_FREE);

    return (FILE_DATA) { RawFile, FileSize };
}

.
.
.

void LoadAllFiles(Array FileNames)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < FileNames.used; i++)
    {
        FILE_DATA file_data = LoadFileIntoMemory(FileNames.array[i].file_name);
        // Store file_data, etc.
    }
    // Do stuff with files here
}
```

As far as I see I am closing all required handles and freeing everything that I can without breaking the program.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: So, what's the C++ tag doing here? If this is not a C++ question, don't tag it as such.

Comment: Please show the full error diagnostic, unabridged. Calling `GetLastError` is meaningless when you hit an access violation.

Comment: Why in the world are you using `VirtualAlloc` as a general-purpose allocator?  If you want pure WinAPI, use `HeapAlloc` or `GlobalAlloc` for general-purpose and `SysAllocString` for wide strings.

Comment: And in your super-specific case of a fixed-size allocation, just do `WCHAR FinalPath[MAX_PATH + 1];`

Comment: I was using HeapAlloc, but I read somewhere that that using VirtualAlloc fixed a similar issue, just haven't changed it back.

Comment: To fix your error, use a debugger, set a breakpoint on the `GetFileAttributesW` call, and inspect what value is present immediately before the call.

Comment: before the GetFileattributesW call, I am getting ERROR_SEM_NOT_FOUND (errno 187) or ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (errno 87) as error from GetLastError. The actual path is correct.

Comment: the exact exception is:
Exception thrown at 0x7753786E (ntdll.dll) in Untitled.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0031002D.

Comment: Are you compiling with `_UNICODE` or `UNICODE` defined? That is, are you sure you're using `wchar_t` for `TCHAR`? (I suppose there would be compiler errors or warning if you weren't, but just thought I'd check.)

Comment: I am compiling with UNICODE enabled

Comment: Why are you using TCHARs, but don't use the generic WinAPI functions (e.g. GetFileAttributes instead of GetFileAttributesW or -A)? Also you should use the TEXT macro to define string literals in that case. Not doing so and mixing it up will lead to all sorts of issues, at the very latest when switching between unicode and non unicode.

Comment: *Access violation reading location 0x0031002D* - this mean you have buffer overflow. your overwrite pointer *FinalPath* with file name ( "-1" )

Comment: how call *VirtualFree* always error, `CloseHandle(FileSize);` - yes ? use *VirtualAlloc* .. errors and must be here

Comment: Side note: Even if you have 16GB RAM in your system, if you target 32 bit, then your program can use at most 2GB (3GB with special care). If you need to use more RAM, then you have to target 64 bit.

Comment: @fpi A 32-bit process gets a full 4GB of address space on a 64-bit version of Windows when requested (`IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`) (see [4-Gigabyte Tuning: BCDEdit and Boot.ini](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/4-gigabyte-tuning)). Address space is what generally limits memory use. RAM is just a performance optimization.

Comment: @IInspectable Do not confuse virtual address space (4GB) and space available to the application.

Comment: @fpi I don't. The full 4GB of address space are available to the application under the conditions spelled out in my previous comment. There's a link to online documentation as well.

Comment: @IInspectable Is it the sentence "On 64-bit editions of Windows, 32-bit applications marked with the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag have 4 GB of address space available." that you refer to? I interpret that like this: The total virtual address space is 4GB. Out of that 4GB address space, only 2GB (default) or up to 3GB (Need configuration) are usable by user application. The rest is used by Windows. If I am wrong, please point me to the exact sentence in the documentation you refer. Thanks.

Comment: @fpi Yes, your interpretation is wrong. It is based on what you apparently know about 32-bit versions of the OS, but ignores that this no longer applies when running 32-bit code on 64-bit versions of the OS. The sentence you quoted is quite unambiguously using the phrase *"available"*. Yes, this really means available to the application. If you continue reading you'll find more information that's hard to map to your interpretation. If in doubt, write a program that allocates pages of memory until it runs out of memory and then reports the size of memory allocated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating enough memory with `VirtualAlloc()`, thus your `concat()` function can cause a **buffer overflow**.  Since you are compiling with `UNICODE` enabled, `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, which is 2 bytes in size.  You need to take that size into account when allocating memory for `FinalPath`, as well as when clearing `FinalPath` with `memset()`.

Change this:

```
PTCHAR FinalPath = VirtualAlloc(NULL, MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
...
memset(FinalPath, 0, MAX_PATH);
```

To this:

```
PTCHAR FinalPath = VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(TCHAR) * MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
...
memset(FinalPath, 0, sizeof(TCHAR) * MAX_PATH);
```

There are other problems with your code, too.  You are not checking if `VirtualAlloc()` is successful before using the returned pointer.  You are leaking the allocated memory if `CreateFileW()` fails.  And you are declaring `FileSize` twice.

Try this instead:

```c
FILE_DATA LoadFileIntoMemory(const TCHAR* FileName)
{
    PTCHAR FinalPath = VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(TCHAR) * MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!FinalPath)
        return (FILE_DATA){ NULL, 0 };

    PTCHAR FilePath = TEXT("C:\\Users\\invasi0nZ\\"); // 

    concat(FinalPath, FilePath, MAX_PATH);
    concat(FinalPath, FileName, MAX_PATH);

    if (!FileExists(FinalPath))
    {
        memset(FinalPath, 0, sizeof(TCHAR) * MAX_PATH);

        FilePath = TEXT("C:\\Users\\invasi0nZ\\Documents\\");

        concat(FinalPath, FilePath, MAX_PATH);
        concat(FinalPath, FileName, MAX_PATH);
    }

    HANDLE File = CreateFile(FinalPath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (File == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        VirtualFree(FinalPath, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return (FILE_DATA){ NULL, 0 };
    }

    VirtualFree(FinalPath, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    DWORD FileSize = GetFileSize(File, NULL);
    if (FileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        CloseHandle(File);
        return (FILE_DATA){ NULL, 0 };
    }

    PBYTE RawFile = VirtualAlloc(NULL, FileSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!RawFile)
    {
        CloseHandle(File);
        return (FILE_DATA){ NULL, 0 };
    }

    DWORD dwRead;
    if (!ReadFile(File, RawFile, FileSize, &dwRead, NULL))
    {
        VirtualFree(RawFile, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        RawFile = NULL;
        dwRead = 0;
    }

    CloseHandle(File);

    return (FILE_DATA) { RawFile, dwRead };
}
```

That being said, you don't really need `FileExists()` at all, as `CreateFile()` can tell you whether the file exists or not, thus avoiding a race condition in your code if another process creates/deletes the file after you check for its existence but before you open it.

You should also get rid of `VirtualAlloc()` for `FinalPath`, you don't need to allocate that string dynamically.  Just declare the array statically instead.

And the Win32 API has functions for concatenating path segments together, so you don't need to write your own.  It also has functions for querying the paths of the user's profile and Documents folders, you should not hard-code those paths.

Try something more like this instead:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <pathcch.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

HANDLE OpenFileInFolder(CSIDL FolderID, const TCHAR *FileName)
{
    TCHAR FilePath[MAX_PATH];

    HRESULT Res = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, FolderID, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, FilePath);
    if (Res != S_OK)
    {
        SetLastError(Res);
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    Res = PathCchCombine(FilePath, MAX_PATH, FilePath, FileName);
    if (Res != S_OK)
    {
        SetLastError(Res);
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return CreateFile(FilePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
}

FILE_DATA LoadFileIntoMemory(const TCHAR* FileName)
{
    HANDLE File = OpenFileInFolder(CSIDL_PROFILE, FileName);
    if ((File == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) && (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND))
        File = OpenFileInFolder(CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, FileName);

    if (File == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return (FILE_DATA){ NULL, 0 };

    DWORD FileSize = GetFileSize(File, NULL);
    if (FileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        CloseHandle(File);
        return (FILE_DATA){ NULL, 0 };
    }

    PBYTE RawFile = VirtualAlloc(NULL, FileSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!RawFile)
    {
        CloseHandle(File);
        return (FILE_DATA){ NULL, 0 };
    }

    DWORD dwRead;
    if (!ReadFile(File, RawFile, FileSize, &dwRead, NULL))
    {
        VirtualFree(RawFile, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        RawFile = NULL;
        dwRead = 0;
    }

    CloseHandle(File);

    return (FILE_DATA) { RawFile, dwRead };
}
```